# I am going do a project in artificial neural networks which language i can prefer

Tags: java, matlab, artificial-intelligence

I have some experience in working with java, but many are telling MATLAB will be a better option for doing projects in Artificial Neural Networks. Can anybody give proper suggestions to choose a language, so that i won't struggle in the middle.

I am expecting answers about the merits and demerits of the both MATLAB and java , in terms of my project and the learning curve of both the languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MATLAB available then use that. MATLAB is quite easy to learn and for a neural network you will mostly use matrix operations and perhaps a few control structures like `for` and `if`.

I would very much think learning the MATLAB syntax for this is *a lot easier* than implementing (good) matrix operations in Java.

The hard part about neural networks is getting the math correct, not the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You won't struggle in the middle wether you choose MATLAB or java to implement a neural network (a perceptron to begin with I guess), but I suggest you do it with the language you have most experienced in (I hope my sentence is grammatically correct, I'm not english native speaker).

With java, you'll have to implement simple matrix computations, but with MATLAB, you'll have to learn a new syntax for everything...

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, choose the language you're most proficient with unless you can find a good reason to do otherwise.

Good luck and welcome to Stackoverflow. :)